# BizTalk WCF-OracleDB (post-)polling(-available)-statements

Tags: wcf, oracle11g, biztalk

I have a general question regarding polling within transaction using WCF-OracleDB adapter, to make sure one (or more) rows polled also gets updated to be polled only once.

In WCF-SQL I normally use polling(available)-statements. In PollingAvailableStatement I use a simple COUNT(*) query. In PollingStatement I normally query next row(s) and store its ID(s) locally. Then I both query data AND update the rows with status to make sure the polled row(s) never gets polled again. And, if something goes wrong, it is rolled back by the AmbientTransaction.

How do I use PostPollingStatement to achieve the same with the WCF-OracleDB-adapter? What I miss is a "reference" to the rows I polled, to make sure only correct rows gets updated status.

I have tried to google this, of course, but everyone seems to avoid this requirement...?

Comment: Can you make to stored procedure that returns the data update the rows?  e.g. select the data into a temporary table, select from the temporary table to return to BizTalk, then update the original rows using those in the temporary table, and then drop the temporary table.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yes, that is probably the solution I will end up with. I was just wondering why they have their PostPollingStatement at all. Of course, you can do whatever you want that has no connection to the acutal rows returned...

Comment: So did you try that approach and did it work?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf No, I have not found a solution yet (summer vacation), but continued it today. Problem is that I am not very good at Oracle... I will document found solution in time.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I have now posted my answer to this query...see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to find any combination of features in Oracle to use same solution as for SQL Server having a procedure to both update polling status AND return data. Hence, there must be another solution for safe polling against an Oracle database.

Oracle has two modes of transaction isolation levels, and you need to use **Serializable** in order for polling to work satisfactory. I think it is like a "snapshot" of the database you get when you enter the serializable mode. And you are isolated from changes by other users you would get if you used ReadCommitted instead. When you commit, other users will see your changes and you will see theirs. To avoid other users to interfere while in serializable mode, make sure to lock rows using **FOR UPDATE**. It will be released when you (or BizTalk) commit changes.

Bottomline, in serializable mode, same query will always return same result (if you did not change it yourself). This is how you can update only rows that you previously polled, the missed "reference" in my question.

Also, **UseAmbientTransaction** must be used to ensure BizTalk to successfully roll back transaction if there are problems. Using PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION, as proposed by some, is not an option because it is a sub-transaction that cannot be rolled back by the transaction BizTalk started.

> Note: **EnableBizTalkCompatibilityMode** should also be set to True, but I have
>   not found any explanation of why or what it does.

So, with the above set configuration, the WCF-OracleDB adapter will enter serializable mode automatically before executing PollingStatement, you will be able to receive data and update polling status using same query as PollingStatement, and adapter will commit changes if PostPollingStatement is successful. If not, AmbientTransaction makes sure your changes are not commited.

And, configuration of pollings statements:

**PollingAvailableStatement**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <Table> WHERE POLLED = 0
```

**PollingStatement**

```
SELECT * FROM <Table> WHERE POLLED = 0 ORDER BY Date ASC FOR UPDATE
```

**PostPollingStatement**

```
 UPDATE <Table> SET POLLED = 1 WHERE POLLED = 0
```

In real world scenarios, you will probably also have to consider batching (using ROWNUM in Oracle), which means you need to construct your queries similar to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <Table> 
WHERE PK IN 
(
    SELECT PK
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM <Table>
        WHERE POLLED = 0
        ORDER BY PK ASC
     )
     WHERE ROWNUM <=10
)
FOR UPDATE;
```

and:

```
UPDATE <Table> 
SET POLLED = 1
WHERE PK IN 
(
    SELECT PK
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM <Table>
        WHERE POLLED = 0
        ORDER BY PK ASC
     )
     WHERE ROWNUM <=10
)
```

Point here is that WHERE and ORDER BY must be executed first, then ROWNUM is based on that sub-query (or view).